How to Send Mobile Push to a Specific DeviceID in Salesforce Marketing Cloud?
I have encountered an issue where push notifications are sent to all active DeviceIDs associated with a contact by default. While this behavior ensures broad coverage, it introduces several challenges:

Reporting Discrepancy: The reports show a higher number of sent push notifications than were actually intended, since every DeviceID linked to a contact receives the push.
Unnecessary Notifications: Some devices might no longer be actively used by the contact, leading to redundant notifications.
Campaign Efficiency: For specific use cases, I only need to target one DeviceID (e.g., the most recently registered device or a specific one).

Question:
Is there any way to configure SFMC (within Journey Builder or Mobile Studio) to send Mobile Push notifications only to a specific DeviceID rather than all DeviceIDs linked to a contact?

Are you aware of the _PushAddress data view?
I would suggest writing a query that pulls in a contacts most recent deviceID.
Once obtained, you can use this data as an entry to a journey, for example.
I would test this out!

It won't work. You need subscriberkey to send a push from the journey. Then the push is sent to all associated devices with the specified subscriberkey
